# Copyrights and Patents on Board games?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about copyrights and Patents that are related to Board and Card games ?

Answer (score 4):

I really think this should be off topic.  I can see a question about who currenly owns a Copyright or trademark on a game, but questions about the legal implications of the law or breaking them should be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is more of a game design question than a GAME question, and should be moved to the other site.

Comment: What other site?

Comment: @Pat Ludwig: I think the original reference was to the game DESIGN site. But it's been through a couple iterations.

Comment: I think that was *my* suggested game design site! It lasted about 15 seconds.