# Should we burninate [legal]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The consensus on meta seems to be that legal questions are off-topic for the Board Games site:

- [Are legal questions on topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1666/9999)
- [Are game copyright issues on topic here?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2079/9999)
- [Copyrights and Patents on Board games?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/537/9999)
- [Card Game Legal Questions are off topic (apparently) can this be added to the of topic FAQ?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1129/9999)

If that is the case, we should burninate the [legal](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag.  The existence of this tag and its description implies that question about game copyright are on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that we burninate [legal](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) based on the question that you linked and the fact that it is a very bad idea to get legal advice from random people on the internet.

As a note on law.se they actually have a close reason regarding asking for legal advice. Given that a site dedicated to law has a rule like that I feel that a site dedicated to games with no expected legal knowledge should also take a similar stance though we don't need it as a specific close reason at this time.

[Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice)

Comment: Law.se needs that because there's a line people aren't supposed to cross between asking about the law and asking for legal advice - I don't see that happening here as much as it will on law, but for the record I think we should leave all legal questions to law SE

Comment: @Andrew it is still a bad idea for people to ask for legal advice from random people on the internet as well as giving legal advice to random people on the internet.